# Lightweight Relational database for BlackBerry OS 4.7

Tags: blackberry, embedded-database

I'm writing an app for BlackBerry OS 4.7 and would greatly benefit from having a lightweight relational database such as SQLite that my application can use to store data locally on the device. SQLite is coming out with 5.0, which is still in beta.

Can anyone recommend any other alternatives that permit commercial use?

Additional information:
- Concurrent access not required
- Transactions not required

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I've tried using Derby, but this is where I hit a roadblock:

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + "derbyDB;create=true", "");

DriverManager cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building your app in java you could consider hsqldb ([hsqldb.org](http://hsqldb.org)), since you can run it embedded in your application.